# JMeter PreProcessor - JSON EXtractor: Nested object

Tags: json, jmeter, nested-object

In the response body of my request, it receives the following JSON:

```
`{"C6666111B946":{"status":"NOT-ADDED"}}`
```

I need to get to the item "C6666111B946" to save it as a variable, so the question is what do I have to enter in the JSON Path expressions field to access it?

[image]

I've already tried with $..* but then I only receive `{"status": "NOT-ADDED"}`

Can somebody help me to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JMES Path Extractor with below JMESPath expression:

> keys(@)

This ends up with this configuration:

[image: JMESPath Configuration]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please look at this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149040/is-it-possible-to-use-wild-cards-in-json-validation-or-ignore-some-values-in-jso/65149491#65149491